# appendRow doesn't work

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

Here's the code which doesn't work perfectly

```
var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT Clients,Taches, Jour, Mois, An, Temps FROM Ktemps WHERE Clients="UR"');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    var cont='';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += '"'+ results.getString(col + 1) + '",';

      //ui.alert(rowString);
    }
    var cont=rowString.substring(0, (rowString.length-1));
    var content=new Array();
    content=cont;
    //ui.alert(rowString);
    ui.alert(cont);
    ui.alert(content);
    sheet.appendRow([content]);// doesn't work
    sheet.appendRow(["UR","Analyse des CHR","06/02/2017","2","2017","1.00"]);//perfectly works
```

In the code above, I read information in mySQL and then want to write into cells.

Using a loop I feed a variable in order to feed appendRow method. Unfortunately, It doesn't work with the variable wherease it works with the text manually writen in the function appendRow.

What could I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is that your whole code? You have not defined sheet.

Comment: ` var content=new Array();` does nothing when you do `content=cont` right after it... next `sheet.appendRow([content]);` results in a array with an array.

Comment: Sheet is defined but not in the part of code I copied

Comment: Thx @epascarello
I agree that var content=new Array();` does nothing when you do content=cont. But I tried that to be sure that Content is an array. The fact is that when I send the argument "content to the function, it write in the sheet as if "content" was a single cell. When i write directly an array writen in text with separator in the function, it works. It seems that the function doesn't recognize that the text chain as an array.

Comment: Because substr is a string. There is nothing about it to be an array. Is it a string that looks like the Array? If so than it should be. JSON.parse(rowString)

Comment: Thx for your answer. Should i use JSON.parse fction ?  Rgds.